# is it possible to refactor this into a single method

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of methods that look like these two:

```
   public void SourceInfo_Get()    
   {
        MethodInfo mi = pFBlock.SourceInfo.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
            if (piArr.Length == 0)
            {
                mi.Invoke(pFBlock.SourceInfo, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void SourceAvailable_Get()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = pFBlock.SourceAvailable.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
            if (piArr.Length == 0)
            {
                mi.Invoke(pFBlock.SourceAvailable, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have one method for each property in my pFBlock object. with so little changing between methods I feel like there should be a better way to do this, but I can't think of any.
I'm using VS 2005.

Comment: The method appears to be public.  Why not just invoke it?  What's the point of using reflection?

Comment: this code is auto generated and I don't know if the method exists or if it takes parameters at code generation time.  So I'm using reflection to make sure it exists and doesn't require any parameters before I call.

Comment: can u use 4.0 features? if so, check my answer for the useage of the dynamic keyword. It works fine with code generation and provides a way better performance than pure reflection.

Comment: @Scott - is it not possible to examine the type when the code is generated and only generate the method  if the type has a suitable method or a "no-op" method if it doesn't?

Comment: @Jaster - unfortunately not with vs 2005.

Comment: @tvanfosson - at the point where the code is being generated I just have names as strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about 3 methods?

```
public void SourceInfo_Get()    
{
    SendGet(pFBlock.SourceInfo);
}

public void SourceAvailable_Get()
{
    SendGet(pFBlock.SourceAvailable);
}

private void SendGet(Object obj) {
    MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
    if (mi != null)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
        if (piArr.Length == 0)
        {
            mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to add a helper method that you can pass a parameter into.  You can then use the helper method in your other methods to drastically shorten your code.

Comment: You didn't change the MethodInfo line, but I agree with your logic.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for pointing that out.  I did not notice that difference initially.

Comment: you pass an object as a type?

Comment: @Jaster, I probably chose the parameter names wrong.  Since I wasn't sure of the Type of the variable, I just used `Type`.  I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @jjnguy -- you can use `object obj` since you're doing a `GetType()` anyway.

Comment: since we use reflection, why providing a type? it makes no sence at all. either we have a specific type and can use the method directly, or a generic implementation or we use reflection without a given type.

Comment: @Jaster, I guess I usually stray from passing `object` around.  It can really hamper type safety.

Comment: there is no type safety using reflection at all.

Comment: @Jaster, I know that.  But restricting the type that you can pass into the method would help a little.

Comment: now im exited, how is this going to help? if you know anything about the type that helps you with reflection (providing type safety) you can use a generic with a constraint instead. otherwise its a nonsense limitation.

Comment: @Jaster, I agree that in this case knowing the type parameter is not gonna help. I guess I was just speaking in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the duplicate code something like this

```
private void Source_Get( Object source )
    {
        MethodInfo mi = source.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
            if (piArr.Length == 0)
            {
                mi.Invoke(source, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }

public void SourceInfo_Get()
    {
       Source_Get(pFBlock.SourceInfo);
    }

public void SourceAvailable_Get()
    {
       Source_Get(pFBlock.SourceAvailable)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SourceAvailable_Get()
{
    CallMethod(pFBlock.SourceAvailable);
}

private void CallMethod(object source, String methodName = "SendGet")
{
   MethodInfo mi = source.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
   if (mi != null)
   {
        if (mi.GetParameters().Length == 0)
        {
           mi.Invoke(source, new object[0]);
        }
   }
}
```

or we use Dynamic...

```
public void CallSendGet(object obj)
{
    obj.AsDynamic().SendGet();
}
```

Comment: AsDynamic - What namespace is that method located in?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Source_Get(string memberName)
    {
        object member = pFBlock.GetMember(memberName);
        MethodInfo mi = member.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
            if (piArr.Length == 0)
            {
                mi.Invoke(member, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sometimes separated functions make the code more readable. You shouldn't merge your functions as much as possible.

Comment: your statement: "Sometimes seperated funtions make the code more readable. You shouldn't merge your functions as much as possible." sounds a little bit like that ;) actually merging code is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.  Typed not tested.

```
private void MasterGet(PFBlock pFBlock, string propertyName)
{
    Type t = pFBlock.GetType();

    // Cycle through the properties.
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
    {
         if(p.Name == propertyName)
         {
           MethodInfo mi = p.GetType().GetMethod("SendGet");
              if (mi != null)
              {
                 ParameterInfo[] piArr = mi.GetParameters();
                 if (piArr.Length == 0)
                  {
                      mi.Invoke(p, new object[0]);
                  }
              }
         }
    }
}
```